# How can I change my navbar class to another navbar class based on screen width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I currently have my navbar fixed to the bottom of the page and the list is stacked. Like so:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
   <li>stuff 1</li>
   <li>stuff 2</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

How can I make it so that the navbar is no longer fixed to the bottom but fixed to the left side of the page (I guess using navbar-fixed-left) if the screen width is larger than 320px?

It seems like this is not possible through media queries so I guess I have to use javascript or SASS? (I know very little javascript and absolutely nothing about SASS, so I figured I would first ask if this is even the route I want to go regarding this issue).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> How can I make it so that the navbar is no longer fixed to the bottom
>   but fixed to the left side of the page (I guess using
>   navbar-fixed-left) if the screen width is larger than 320px?

You do it using a media query but you don't change the class name, you change the properties of that class.

for example (just get you started)

```
.navbar-fixed {
  position:fixed;
  left:auto;
  bottom:0;
}
@media(min-width:320px) {
  // this will retain the properties declared above
  .navbar-fixed { // only add new properties of ones you want to change
    left:0;
    bottom:auto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

**Javascript**

```
var navResponsive = function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 320) {
        $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-left').removeClass('navbar-fixed-bottom');
    } else {
        $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-bottom').removeClass('navbar-fixed-left');
    }
};

$(window).on('resize', navResponsive());
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/171/)